# Ubuntu stores variables in the wrong order

Tags: programming, ram, c

So I had this exercise in my class where I had to tell which of the two addresses is bigger when I create two char's in a main function.

Because local variables are stored in the stack that starts with high address and goes down to low address. The answer was easy that the first char has a bigger address.

But then I wrote a little test program:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void)
{
    int a = 3;
    int b = 4;

    printf("Size a: %lu \n"
           "size b: %lu \n",
           sizeof(a),
           sizeof(b));

    printf("Address a: %p \n"
           "Address b: %p \n",
           (void *)&a,
           (void *)&b);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Size a: 4 
size b: 4 
Address a: 0x7fffa1eb8a98 
Address b: 0x7fffa1eb8a9c
```

The output was misleading, the second char address was bigger. I tried the same on a computer at my university and there was everything okay.
Do you know why this is so?

I'm on Ubuntu 13.04 64bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C standard as defined by Kernighan & Ritchie in their book "The C Programming Language" does not define how parameters are passed to functions, not does it define how local variables are stored which leaves it implementation defined.

The documentation for your compiler should tell you how parameters are passed because otherwise you can't write assembly code to link in with it.  For local variables there are even fewer constraints as these will only be accessed from within the function so the compiler may decide not to store the variable in memory at all it could keep it in a register.  As you asked for the address of the variable the compiler has been forced to store it in memory but unless you use a pointer to a particular variable it is not required to.

Two different compilers can do things differently.  A lot of compilers choose to use the stack but others will use registers instead where this is possible and even where they do use the stack the order of parameters is down to the implementation.

The ANSI C standard as not changed this.

In short Ubuntu does not store variables in the wrong order.  The compiler you use in Ubuntu just stores them in a different order than the one you use at university.  Neither is wrong.  They are just different and the compiler documentation should explain how its implemented.

For gcc, which is what most people use in Linux the documentation is [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I understand why there's a problem but I think GCC might have something to do with it... Here's a comparison between GCC and Clang.

```
$ gcc -o test.gcc test.c
$ ./test.gcc
Size a: 4 
size b: 4 
Address a: 0x7fffeef71488 
Address b: 0x7fffeef7148c 


$ clang++ -o test.clang test.c 
$ ./test.clang 
Size a: 4 
size b: 4 
Address a: 0x7fff664573f8 
Address b: 0x7fff664573f4
```

The compiler and its version you're using at uni may be the variable element here.